# What will Twilio do if the destination phone is turn off?

Tags: twilio

Will **twilio** retry for a period of time or will they send us a failed message delivery receipt straight away?

Comment: You could turn your phone off, send yourself a message and see what happens.

Comment: I tried that. The question is "Will twilio retry for a period of time or will they send us a failed message delivery receipt straight away" if the phone is powered off

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio will not retry a call. If the phone is disconnected, it will most likely return `failed` or `no-answer`. In that case you can create a retry routine yourself, or get it to try to call a different number.

You could use something like the following for example to try to handle a `failed` status if you're using TwiML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial action="/handleDialCallStatus.php" method="GET">
        415-123-4567
    </Dial>
    <Say>I am unreachable</Say>
</Response>
```

In this case your `handleDialCallStatus.php` file will always be called, and you can just check the status and handle it however you like.

**CAVEAT**

One thing to look for though is that most times even if the number is disconnected, you will find that it will go straight though voicemail, in which case you will get a `answered` status. If you want to check that your call was answered by a human, you could just request the user to dial a number and get that with the [Gather verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather), and that will tell you.

Some more documentation for that can be found [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-action-dial-call-status-values).

**UPDATE**
You've now clarified this on the comments saying you're talking about SMS, so here's the answer for SMS messages.

Regardless of the phone being `on` or `off` Twilio will deliver this message to the carrier. Twilio will then change the message status to delivered if the phone is turned on providing the carrier gives Twilio this information. In Europe, most carriers will update this, in the US only about half will do.

One caveat to this is the fact that Twilio will only update this information if it's provided by the carrier within 60 minutes.

The carrier on the other hand will try to deliver this message to the device for up to 72 hours, but retries on the carrier side will vary from from carrier to carrier. You can find more information about carrier delivery in this [FAQ](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/how-can-i-troubleshoot-if-an-sms-message-sent-from-twilio-didnt-arrive).

Hope this helps you.

Comment: From twilio support: **Twilio will not try to resend SMS messages that have been undelivered by the carrier. If the device is turned off, most likely the status will change to undelivered and may provide additional error reporting in terms of the reason for nondelivery.**